# работа со стандартным потоком ввода require JS

Tags: javascript, строки, require

Не понимаю как подогнать задачу под форму сдачи

```
    function checkStr(str) {

    let a = str.split(' ');
    let first, second;
    let b = a[0].split('');
    let c = a[1].split('');
    if (b.length !== c.length)
        console.log(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] !== c[i]) {
            first = b[i];
            second = c[i];
            // console.log(`1 word ${first}`);
            // console.log(`2 word ${second}`);
        }
        for (let j = i; j < b.length; j++) {
            if ((first == b[j] && second != c[j]) ||
                (first != b[j] && second == c[j])) {
                console.log(0);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(1);
}

// let str = 'абаб ааах';
checkStr('привет прикол');
```

Для работы со стандартным потоком ввода в JS используйте require('readline'), а для работы со стандартным потоком вывода - console.log(String(data)).
Пример ввода-вывода на JS:

```
    const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    // Введенная строка в переменной line, тут можно написать решение
    console.log(String(result));
    rl.close();
    return;
}).on('close', () => process.exit(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, поможет:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

// Решение
function checkStr(str) {
    let a = str.split(' ');
    let first, second;
    let b = a[0].split('');
    let c = a[1].split('');
    if (b.length !== c.length)
        console.log(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] !== c[i]) {
            first = b[i];
            second = c[i];
            // console.log(`1 word ${first}`);
            // console.log(`2 word ${second}`);
        }
        for (let j = i; j < b.length; j++) {
            if ((first == b[j] && second != c[j]) ||
                (first != b[j] && second == c[j])) {
                console.log(0);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(1);
}

// Ввод
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    checkStr(line)
    rl.close();
    return;
}).on('close', () => process.exit(0));
```